# How do I create different speaking styles for my characters?

Tags: fiction, creative-writing, technique

In my fiction writing, how do I create individual speaking styles for my characters? It is more than giving one or two of them an accent or dialect.

What techniques do you use to vary the structure, rhythm, vocabulary and phrasing of each of your characters?

I find it really hard to do, because all my characters speak like me (of course they do).

Any suggestions?